# intrinsic gas too low: how to increase gas in Mist?

Tags: mist, contract-deployment, gas, out-of-gas

I cannot deploy a contract using Mist because of the error `intrinsic gas too low`

How can I increase the value of it?

[image]

Comment: That seems like a lot of gas to me for a contract you might want to see if there is a problem with the contract

Answer (score 4):

You can type the gas you want in the blue underlined bit. Just click on it and type

Comment: @happycrazy Please accept the answer, by clicking on the tick icon, if this answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

While deploying the contract, you can specify the amount of gas you want to send with the transaction. On the bottom left of the page where your write your code, you can see a slider bar for `Select Fee`, Just use the slider to increase/ decrease the gas you want to send.

Comment: it will be better if you add a screenshot to help him

Comment: Isnt this the gas price - the amount  of ether per gas unit- not the amount of gas?